# NodeJS Express defining custom routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

This is probably a really basic concept that I'm not understanding but in my NodeJS application I am trying to define a custom route.

my directory structure is as follows

```
/application
    /app.js
    /package.json
    /node_modules
    /public
    /routes
        /control
            /users.js
    /views
        /control
            /users.ejs
```

Which I am happy with because I want to keep the routes and views in a 1 to 1 relationship because I will eventually end up with something like

```
/application
    /app.js
    /package.json
    /node_modules
    /public
    /routes
        /control
            /users.js
            /system.js
        /tools
            /stock.js
            /report.js
    /views
        /control
            /users.ejs
            /system.ejs
        /tools
            /stock.ejs
            /report.ejs
```

So I don't want to end up with a /routes/index.js file with a hideous amount of routing code inside.

It seems to work while my app.js file is as follows

```
//==============================================================================
// setup
//==============================================================================

var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");

var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var message = null;

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

//==============================================================================
// routes
//==============================================================================

var users = require("./routes/control/users");
app.get("/", users.users);

//==============================================================================
// start server
//==============================================================================

app.listen(port, function() {

   message = "Server Started : Port " + port;
   console.log(message);

});
```

Although I can see this is going to end up looking like

```
//==============================================================================
// setup
//==============================================================================

var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");

var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var message = null;

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

//==============================================================================
// routes
//==============================================================================

// control

var users = require("./routes/control/users");
app.get("/", users.users);

var system = require("./routes/control/system");
app.get("/", system.system);

// tools

var stock = require("./routes/tools/stock");
app.get("/", stock.stock);

var report = require("./routes/tools/report");
app.get("/", report.report);

//==============================================================================
// start server
//==============================================================================

app.listen(port, function() {

   message = "Server Started : Port " + port;
   console.log(message);

});
```

So I don't really want to have that many requires but doing it like the following doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why

```
// control

var control = require("./routes/control");

app.get("/", control.users.users);
app.get("/", control.system.system);

// tools

var tools = require("./routes/tools");

app.get("/", tools.stock.stock);
app.get("/", tools.report.report);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say:

```
var control = require("./routes/control");
```

Node will do the followings:

1. Since you privided a *relative path* to require, it will search for a *routes* directory within the current folder and in that directory search for a **control.js** file. It can't find *control.js* file so then:
2. Search for a **control.json** file. but it also can't find that
   file. then:
3. Search for a **control directory**. It finds such a directory. opens
   it and search for a **package.json** file to look into its
       *main* property. but it also cant find such a file. then:
4. Search for a **index.js** file but also there is no such a file

By default when you give a folder path to *require*, it does not load *.js* files inside that folder automatically it looks for **package.json** file and if it's not there it loads **index.js**. i. e. It looks for an entry point.

So make an **index.js** in your control folder:

```
/routes
  /control
    /users.js
    /system.js
    /index.js
```

index.js:

```
module.exports = {
  users: require('./users');
  system: require('./system');
};
```

Do this also for your **tools** directory and your last approach should work.

**Note** that you could consider using [**express.Router**](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router) to manage routes.

Comment: Thanks a bunch this answer solved my problem and the code seems very simple and easy to use

Answer (score 6):

You can use the express Router object to chain your routes. Here's an example

**/app.js**

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');

// as noted by Paul in the comments, 
// you could use `app.use(routes)` for simplicity
app.use('/', routes);
```

**/routes/index.js**

```
var routes = require('express').Router();

routes.route('/test')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.send(req.originalUrl);
    });

routes.use('/control', require('./control/user'));

module.exports = routes;
```

**/routes/control/user.js**

```
var routes = require('express').Router();

routes.route('/test')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.send(req.originalUrl);
    });

module.exports = routes;
```

So for the route defined in index.js, you'll need to send a GET request to `/test` while in user.js, you will need to send a GET request to `/control/test` to get a response.

This way all you need to include in the main js file, app.js in your case, is the main routes file, which is index.js under the routes directory. Either way, you will still need to do one require statement for each file that exports a router object.

Comment: Good example, though it should be noted that you can simplify your first `app.use()` statement thusly:  `app.use(routes);`, as the root path is the default.

Comment: @Paul Yes, that's true. Copy paste habit. :)

Comment: This looks like a really great answer the one by @dNitro was just a bit easier for me to understand

Comment: @Trent Whatever works best for the developer I'd say. If you need to refactor your code later on, you can use this as a basis.